# How to get the Solr index sizes via a curl command

Tags: solr

How to get the Solr cluster index sizes via a curl command?
(without getting the data folder size)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to find the API endpoint for a specific set of data is to use the Solr UI while looking at the "Network" tab of your browser's development tools. This will show all requests being made to the backend Solr service, and you can then look at the response from each endpoint when you've navigated to the page showing the index size.

The core overview shows the index size under the "Replication" header, and that is populated from a request to /replication:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/corename/replication?command=details&wt=json
```

If we look at the response from that endpoint, we can see that the JSON contains the following key and value:

```
"details":{
  "indexSize":"6.49 KB",
  ...
```